# Fungible type as erc20 in erc1155

Tags: erc-1155

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/ERC1155.sol";

contract AwesomeGame is ERC1155 {
    uint256 public constant GOLD = 0;
    uint256 public constant SILVER = 1;
    uint256 public constant SWORD = 2;
    uint256 public constant SHIELD = 3;
    uint256 public constant CROWN = 4;

    constructor() ERC1155("https://awesomegame.com/assets/{id}.json") {
        _mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SILVER, 10**18, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SWORD, 1000, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, SHIELD, 1000, "");
        _mint(msg.sender, CROWN, 1, "");
    }
}
```

This is the example from [alchemy](https://docs.alchemy.com/docs/how-to-create-erc-1155-tokens). So `Gold` here can be fungible ERC-20 where the quantity is `10**18`.

Questions

1. Majority of coins/currencies listed on exchanges is ERC-20 type and not 1155? Can GOLD be used as ERC-20 and have monetary value?
2. Isn't the quantity for GOLD should be something like `supply * 10**18`? i.e. `100000000 * 10**18`

Answer (score 0):

1. The majority of coins/currencies listed on exchanges is ERC-20 type, not ERC-1155. GOLD can be used as ERC-20 and have monetary value as ERC-1155 can perform the function of ERC-20 and ERC-721 and even both simultaneously.
2. The quantity of GOLD has a maximum value of 2**(256)-1 (`uint256`). As long as the supply doesn't exceed that, it's allowed.

Comment: #1 can erc1155 GOLD token be listed on exchanges then?

#2 alright but `10**18` is just decimals meaning only 1 token. so `_mint(msg.sender, GOLD, 10**18, "");` this is just minting only 1 GOLD token. so i'm assuming it should have minted more tokens?